# How do I list all files in a directory in Linux using bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, printing, formatting, command

I have been trying to list all the files from the "junk_dir" in a formatted style, listing them off by file name, file size and file type. Although I am not getting these printed off in a formatted way, I am getting them printed out. However, on line 10, I get an error from the command promp tsaying

```
./junk-skeleton.sh: line 10: [1001=: command not found
```

The following is my code.

```
#! /bin/bash 

list_junk()
{
    echo "Junk Directory"

   format="%8s%10s%10s  %-s\n"
   printf "$format" "File" "Size" "Type"
   printf "$format" "----" "----" "----"
   if [$(id -u)= "0"]; then
      dir_list="/home/student/bin/junk_dir/*"
   else
      dir_list=$HOME
   fi

  for file in $dir_list; do
      filename=$(ls -al /home/student/bin/junk_dir)
      filesize=$(wc -c /home/student/bin/junk_dir)
      filetype=$(ls --file-type /home/student/bin/junk_dir)

      printf "$format" $filename $filesize $filetype
   done
}
```

Also, if anybody has help formatting the printed results, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Leave a space after `[` and before `]`

Comment: @Inian I have tried that, What I got back was `./junk-skeleton.sh: line 10: [: 1001=: unary operator expected`

Comment: Try: `if  [ $(id -u) = 0 ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need spaces around both the brackets, and between the shell command and the equals sign.

```
if [ $(id -u) = "0" ]; then echo ROOT; fi
```